# How to exclude match multiple strings with a regex in perl?

Tags: regex

I want to exclude matching multiple strings "[", "standalone", ":", "]" and also multiple whitespaces and only want to match ">". How can i do this with a perl regex?

```
qr 'm/^\s*(?!.*([|standalone|:|master|])).*[#>]\s*?$/',
```

This is the string:

```
sw-sn2410 [standalone: master] >
```

And, from this strings i want to exclude " [standalone: master] " from matching.

Comment: What code have you tried and how does it fail for you? Please show us some minimal code with test data included. Most likely, an approach to exclude strings will use [lookaround assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) to match (say) `s` but not `standalone`

Comment: please share sample input and the expected output.

Comment: what him said.  Show us your code.  What is it doing that you do not expect.  What is it not doing that you expect.  Test cases please

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Please show exactly what you want the match to be. And show more examples.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^.*\[standalone:\s*master\]\s*\K>$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeVHsO/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to match, what you **don't** want and replace that with an empty string. The regex used for that is simply:

```
 ( \[standalone: master\])
```

Then replace the match with an empty string, that will give you:

```
sw-sn2410 >
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Poul.
This is what i exactly want.
But i am new to perl. can you please be a little more comprehensive?